# Applicative Instance for (Monad m, Monoid o) => m o?

Tags: haskell, monads, gadt, applicative, monoids

Sorry for the terrible title. I'm trying to make an instance of `Applicative` for a `Monad` wrapping a type that is a `Monoid`.

```
instance (Monad m, Monoid o) => Applicative (m o) where
    pure x = return mempty
    xm <*> ym = do
        x <- xm
        y <- ym
        return $ x `mappend` y
```

This doesn't work; GCHi complains with:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Applicative' should have kind `* -> *',
but `m o' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Applicative (m o)'
```

I realise that what I've written above may make no sense. Here is the context: I am trying to use the `compos` abstraction as described in the paper [*A pattern for almost compositional functions*](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/local_75172.pdf). Taking this tree (using the GADT version of `compos`; I've simplified it a lot):

```
data Tree :: * -> * where
    Var :: String -> Expr
    Abs :: [String] -> Expr -> Expr
    App :: Expr -> [Expr] -> Expr

class Compos t where
    compos :: Applicative f => (forall a. t a -> f (t a)) -> t c  -> f (t c)

instance Compos Tree where
    compos f t =
        case t of
            Abs ps e -> pure Abs <*> pure ps <*> f e
            App e es -> pure App <*> f e <*> traverse f es
            _ -> pure t
```

I'm going to write a lot of functions which descend the tree and return a list of say errors or a set of strings whilst also requiring state as it goes down (such as the binding environment), such as:

```
composFoldM :: (Compos t, Monad m, Monoid o) => (forall a. t a -> m o) -> t c -> m o
composFoldM f = ??? 

checkNames :: (Tree a) -> State (Set Name) [Error]
checkNames e =
    case e of
        Var n -> do
            env <- get
            -- check that n is in the current environment
            return $ if Set.member n env then [] else [NameError n]
        Abs ps e' -> do
            env <- get
            -- add the abstractions to the current environment
            put $ insertManySet ps env
            checkNames e'
        _ -> composFoldM checkNames e

data Error = NameError Name
insertManySet xs s = Set.union s (Set.fromList xs)
```

I think these should all be able to be abstracted away by making `composFoldM` use `compos` for the `(Monad m, Monoid o) => m o` structure. So to use it with the GADT `Applicative` version of `compos` found on page  575/576 of [the paper](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/local_75172.pdf). I think I need to make an `Applicative` instance of this structure. How would I do this? Or am I going down completely the wrong path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `Constant` applicative from `Data.Functor.Constant` in the `transformers` package, which you can find [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Constant.html#t%3aConstant).

This `Applicative` has the following instance:

```
instance (Monoid a) => Applicative (Constant a) where
    pure _ = Constant mempty
    Constant x <*> Constant y = Constant (x `mappend` y)
```

You can then compose `Constant` with any other applicative using `Compose` from `Data.Functor.Compose` (also in the `transformers` package), which you can find [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t%3aCompose).

`Compose` has this `Applicative` instance:

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)
```

You can then `Compose` your `Constant` applicative with any other `Applicative` (like `State`) to keep both some state and a running `Monoid` tally.

More generally, you should read the paper [The Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf), which discusses these patterns in more detail.

Comment: This looks like the thing I need! But how do I actually use it? I tried to do things like `composFoldM f = getCompose . compos (Compose . WrapMonad . Const . f)` but this doesn't work. Are there any examples/explanations of how to combine functors?

Comment: My god. I finally worked it out through trial and improvement. I guess this is how you learn! The right thing is `composFoldM f = liftM getConst . unwrapMonad . getCompose . compos (Compose . WrapMonad . liftM Const . f)`. :D

Comment: @CallumRogers That's exactly right!  That's one of the nice things about Haskell: the type-checker will always steer you towards the correct solution.

Comment: Indeed, one of my favourite things about Haskell.

Comment: `Constant` also exists as `Const` in `Control.Applicative`. Which one should be used?

Comment: @ipsec I'm not completely sure.  If I had to pick then probably `Const` since ` Control.Applicative` is in `base`.

Comment: I used `Const` as it's part of base library. They have exactly the same semantics.